# Material UI Autocomplete changing single to multiSelect based on condition

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm having problems with material UI Autocomplete changing from single select to multiple select based on condition throws error **Cannot read property 'length' of null**

**Here's a codesandbox demonstrating this:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-q0038?file=/demo.js
Here I have created scenario to change from single to multi conditionally

I know I can use another autocomplete component if it's multi but if there any solution to do in single component it will be helpfull

Comment: It seems to be working fine [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5ei2i?file=/demo.js:0-5801).

Comment: @Medi You have assigned null property to multiple but I need to change the component single to multiselect based on condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `key` prop to `ismulti`:

```
<Autocomplete
        multiple={ismulti}
        id="tags-standard"
        key={ismulti} // here
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
```